# startActivityForResult putExtras being recieved as NULL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Hi I am creating a SideActivity to gather some results and pass them back to Main Activity. However, the two strings value from the putextra are NULL rather than the string "20" and the jamSize "medium". Is there a way of passing the data properly?

Here in my Main Activity I have a setOnClickListener and a onActivityResult function.

```
jamButton.setOnClickListener {
           var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SideActivity::class.java)
           intent.putExtra("jamName", "raspberry")
           intent.putExtra("jamPrice", "12.00")
           startActivityForResult(intent, 1) // passing request code value 1

       }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           val jamPrice:String = intent.getStringExtra("jamPrice").toString()
           val jamSize:String = intent.getStringExtra("jamSize").toString()
           val newJam = DataModel("Jam", "$jamSize", "$jamPrice")
           list.add(0, newJam)
           jamAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
       } 
   }
```

Here is my Second Activity

```
completeBtn.setOnClickListener {
           val jamPrice: String = textView2.text.toString()
           val jamSize: String = textView3.text.toString()
           
           val intent = Intent(this@SideActivity, MainActivity::class.java) 

           intent.putExtra("jamPrice", "20.00")
           intent.putExtra("jamSize", jamSize)
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
           finish()
       }
```

Comment: Can you try constructing the `Intent` with no parameters? They're not needed for returning the result and might be interfering.

Comment: In Side Activity, I changed it and the results being recieved back are still NULL:                                                                                                                            
           val intent = Intent() 

           intent.putExtra("jamPrice", "20.00")    
           intent.putExtra("jamSize", jamSize)

Comment: @ShayKin has spotted the bug, however still no need to construct the `Intent` with anything, it just needs your extras

Comment: @HenryTwist Thanks henry for your help. Agreed, the code looks cleaned without the re-construction of the Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onActivityResult don't use this :

```
 val jamPrice:String = intent.getStringExtra("jamPrice").toString()
```

because the intent variable is the Intent of the activity instead use :

```
val jamPrice: String = data?.getStringExtra("jamPrice").toString()
```